# Swift function with successHandler that calls other function with successHandler

Tags: swift, closures

I have a method A that returns a result in a closure. Now this function iterates over other methods B with a successClosure. How do I do this?

PseudoCode:

```
func methodA(successHandler: @escaping () -> (Int)){

   for object in objects{
      object.methodB{
        successHander()
      }
   }

}

func methodB(successHandler: @escaping () -> ()){
   successHander(42)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a better example, with real asynchronous tasks.

The following will create 10 asynchronous tasks, which all call their success handler in a random interval from 0 to 10 seconds:

```
func methodA(successHandler: @escaping (String) -> ()){
    let objects = (1...10).map { "Block \($0)" }

    for object in objects {
        methodB(message: object) { print($0) }
    }

    successHandler("Everything done")
}

func methodB(message: String, successHandler: @escaping (String) -> ()){
    let randomSecs = DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + randomSecs) {
        successHandler(message)
    }
}

methodA {
    print($0)
}

sleep(12000)
```

And using `DispatchGroup` to wait for all subtasks to complete and return their result in the completion block:

```
func methodA(successHandler: @escaping (String, [String]) -> ()){
    let objects = (1...10).map { "Block \($0)" }

    let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    var results: [String] = []

    for object in objects {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        methodB(message: object) {
            print($0)
            results.append($0)
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: queue) {
        successHandler("Everything done", results)
    }
}

func methodB(message: String, successHandler: @escaping (String) -> ()){
    let randomSecs = DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(Int(arc4random_uniform(10)))
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + randomSecs) {
        successHandler(message)
    }
}

methodA {
    print($0, $1)
}

sleep(12000)
```

Note that this is an example of a console application. In a UI app (MacOS/iOS) you can use `DispatchQueue.main` as the notification queue and you won't need `sleep`.